# Vuetify.js Responsive v-toolbar not triggering open/close event

Tags: responsive-design, vue.js, pug, vuetify.js

I'm attempting to create a responsive navigation toolbar (using the [v-toolbar component](https://vuetifyjs.com/components/toolbars) and [router-links](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/named-routes.html)). I'd like to create a navigationbar that collapses into a responsive vertical list (similar to [bootstrap navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)) so that when on mobile a hamburger menu appears and a vertical list can be shown and hidden by clicking on the hamburger icon.

I've created a toolbar ([see here](https://codepen.io/atgarbett/pen/wPYMoY)) however when I reduce the size of the display to activate the responsive toolbar the burger menu does not expand to show the router-links. Similarly, the router-links do not activate (I suspect that the anchor tag is being overridden by the v-btn).

HTML (Pug)

```
div#app
  nav
    v-toolbar
      v-toolbar-title
        router-link.nav-item(to="/") Mysite
      v-spacer
      v-toolbar-side-icon.hidden-md-and-up
      v-toolbar-items.hidden-sm-and-down
        v-btn(flat)
          router-link.nav-item(to="/about") About
        v-btn(flat)
          router-link.nav-item(to="/contact") Contact
```

**Edit**
Edited code to implement suggestion from LShapz ([updated Codepen here](https://codepen.io/atgarbett/pen/QOZoyg))

```
nav
  v-toolbar.hidden-sm-and-down
    v-toolbar-title
      router-link.nav-item(to="/") MySite
    v-spacer
    v-toolbar-items
      v-btn(flat)
        router-link.nav-item(to="/about") About
      v-btn(flat)
        router-link.nav-item(to="/contact") Contact

  div.hidden-md-and-up
    v-expansion-panel
      v-expansion-panel-content
        div(slot="header")
          router-link.nav-item(to="/") MySite
        v-card
          v-card-text
            router-link.nav-item(to="/about") About
        v-card
          v-card-text
            router-link.nav-item(to="/contact") Contact
```

Can anyone suggest an edit that will allow me to show/hide the responsive menu when clicking the hamburger menu?

Previous codepen
https://codepen.io/atgarbett/pen/wPYMoY

Working codepen
https://codepen.io/atgarbett/pen/QOZoyg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @LShapz has suggested, you can use a combination of v-toolbar and v-expansion-panel. Each of which is shown or hidden depending on the size of the display. This allows for a vertical list style navigation when on smaller displays.

```
nav
  v-toolbar.hidden-sm-and-down
    v-toolbar-title
      router-link.nav-item(to="/") MySite
    v-spacer
    v-toolbar-items
      v-btn(flat)
        router-link.nav-item(to="/about") About
      v-btn(flat)
        router-link.nav-item(to="/contact") Contact

  div.hidden-md-and-up
    v-expansion-panel
      v-expansion-panel-content
        div(slot="header")
          router-link.nav-item(to="/") MySite
        v-card
          v-card-text
            router-link.nav-item(to="/about") About
        v-card
          v-card-text
            router-link.nav-item(to="/contact") Contact
```

See example here: https://codepen.io/atgarbett/pen/QOZoyg

Answer (score 1):

You do not actually have the code for a [v-menu with a list of items](https://vuetifyjs.com/components/menus) on there, nor do have an activator on the v-toolbar-side-icon.

Comment: You also didn't have a v-app - here's a non-Pug version https://codepen.io/lshapz/pen/qVJRqe

Comment: Hey LShapz, I have the v-app within a parent component however the v-menu is a good shout. The codepen you've offered has very strange behaviour when you click on the hamburger menu in that a vertical menu pops up. Is the twitter style drop down not supported on Vuetify?

Comment: ah, I see what you mean. I guess for that you'd use something closer to an  Expansion Panel than a Menu? (I don't know if you can change the trigger icon from an arrow to the hamburger / side icon.) BTW, have you checked out the vuetify Discord? it's very active and helpful, and the creator John Leider is on there every day, so he might have already helped someone achieve something like the implementation you want
 https://vuetifyjs.com/components/expansion-panels